# Syntax highlight javascript templates within <script type='text/html'> elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, vim, underscore.js

In my Ruby on Rails templates I write underscore templates within `<script type='text/html'>` elements.

I'm using rails.vim and other plugins, but syntax highlighting and identation rules don't work for the htmls inside these elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a partial. That also keeps the page with all the html scripts from growing into a monster.

```
<script type="text/x-underscore">
  <%= render 'my_partial_with_syntax_highlighting' %>
</script>
```

Ditto for using something other than text/html for content type.