# Make Vim correctly highlight script type="text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, vim, syntax-highlighting

How can I get Vim to correctly syntax-highlight in a situation such as this (used, e.g. with [Knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)):

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
  <!-- This should be rendered as HTML -->
  <div>Some template</div>
</script>

<script>
  //This should be rendered as Javascript
  var x = function() { return 3; }
</script>
```

The solution given [here](https://gist.github.com/sjl/1298333) involves editing Vim's internal syntax file, which seems wrong, and it specifically looks for "`text/javascript`" which is [no longer needed in `<script>` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323376/do-html5-script-tag-need-type-javascript).

I assume the solution is some sort of syntax plugin I can keep in my `.vim` directory but am not familiar enough with Vim's syntax internals to figure it out.

(Note that [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157519/syntax-highlight-javascript-templates-within-script-type-text-html-elements) don't apply as I'm not using Ruby on Rails.)

Comment: Well, you will obviously need to edit the HTML syntax script and/or the JavaScript syntax script as they are quite old. Try something and come back with a real actionable question when you are stuck.

Comment: Right, see where I "am not familiar enough with Vim's syntax internals to figure it out". A starting point would be helpful, at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you: https://coderwall.com/p/vgk5-q/make-vim-play-nice-with-html-templates-inside-script-tags.

In case the link above is broken one day - put the following code into `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`:

```
unlet b:current_syntax
syn include @HTML $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim
syn region htmlTemplate start=+<script [^>]*type *=[^>]*text/template[^>]*>+
\                       end=+</script>+me=s-1 keepend
\                       contains=@HTML,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
```

Somebody should write a plugin for that! ;)

Comment: Of course, to be an closer fit for the OP's case, replace `[^>]*text/template[^>]` with `[^>]*text/html[^>]`.

Answer (score 1):

First copy the vim's internal html syntax file to `$HOME/.vim/syntax/html.vim` so that you only change the behaviour for yourself not globally.

Then find the line starting `syn region  javaScript` and replace it with two lines

```
syn region  script_notype start=+<script>+ keepend end=+</script>+me=s-1 contains=@htmlJavaScript,htmlCssStyleComment,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
syn region  script_jstype start=+<script[^>]*type="text/javascript"[^>]*>+ keepend end=+</script>+me=s-1 contains=@htmlJavaScript,htmlCssStyleComment,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
```

The first line is for plain `<script>` tab, the second for `<script type="text/javascript">`.

However, this won't cover a situation with `<script>` tag without `type` attribute having other attributes. This case should get javascript syntax but won't. I guess this is a minor problem.

Comment: This works for <script type="text/html"> but <script type="text/javascript"> no longer formats correctly.

Comment: @Dan: Can you double check if you have set it up the same? For me, it works properly even for `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't solve this. It works on my machine perfectly and doesn't on yours... Try to play with it for a while, I believe you'll be able to get it working.